# How do I return the code presented during the "Inspect" on Chrome for any given website?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am currently running a webscraping and I essentially want to return the code exactly as it is interpreted by my browser, as I then run it through beautifulsoup and look for specific classes/divs.

The problem is that the website is partially created using javascript so I am not able to simply use a regular request, I have tried to use Selenium and then either

`driver.page_source`

or alternatively

```
driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
```

However both of these methods return something significantly different than to what I can see on the screen. I essentially just want it to return exactly what I see when I use the inspect tool and preferably in a format that I can run through beautifulsoup.

I am pretty much at a loss here and have tried to google for a significant amount of time, but I am not able to find an answer.

Any and all ideas are very welcome

Comment: well Selenium should be doing the trick. Unless you update your question that provides the specific code you are using and the url, to reproduce the issue, unfortunately, it's tough to help out with specific solutions. Also providing an example of your desired output helps to. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you get a chance.

Comment: Got it thanks, I will look through!